# Distribution of people diagnosed with dementia by age

Tags: data-request, medical, demographics

I am looking for a chart that shows, for each age, percentage of the population of that age that has been diagnosed with dementia and given prescription drugs for dementia, as part of a histogram that shows age in the x-axis. On the y-axis, I would like the bar charts the histogram to show both the number of patients diagnosed with dementia for the first time duty that year, as well as number of patients having dementia during that year or any of the previous years.

Thanks.